# Can `auto &&` parameters be perfect forwarded?

Tags: c++, c++14, perfect-forwarding

For template functions I use perfect forwarding like this:

```
template<typename T>
void f (T && v)
{
  g (std::forward<T> (v));
}
```

How do I perfect forward `auto &&` parameters in `C++14` lambda expressions?

```
auto f = [] (auto && v)
  {
    g (std::forward<??> (v));
  };
```

(Tried to google for it but didn't get any good hits on the keywords I picked)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, they can be perfect-forwarded by means of [`decltype()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) specifier:

```
auto f = [](auto&& v)
{
    g(std::forward<decltype(v)>(v));
    //             ~~~~~~~~~~^
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dd678ec5a30a2a6)

Comment: `static_cast` instead of `std::forward` little bit more suitable. Due to `std::forward< T >()` is sematically identical to `static_cast< T && >()` and `T` here is always reference.